# More efficient of way of operating on numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, one with an array of 2 dimensional vectors `(z1_i,z2_i)`'s and the other is just an array of 1 dimensional variables `c_i`'s (the i's here denote the index of the array). I want to operate on the two arrays to get a single array of one dimensional variable of the form `z1_i*c_i + z2_i*(1-c_i)` (again, the subscript i refer to the index of the array). For example:

```
2D_samples= np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
1D_samples = np.array([1, 0])
# desired output would be np.array([1, 4])
# Specifically, [1*1+2*(1-1), 3*0+4(1-0)]=[1,4].
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this without executing a for loop? Thanks.

Doing it by for loop would give:

```
output = np.zeros(2D_samples)
for i in range(len(2D_samples)):
  output[i] = 2D_samples[i][0] * 1D_samples[i] + 2D_samples[i][1] * (1 - c[i])
```

Comment: 1-c is [0,-1]. why is the desired result [1, 4] and not [1,-4]?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, what I had in mind is 3 * (0) + 4 * (1-0) = 4.

Comment: it's unclear what you want. where does the 0 and the 1-0 come from?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: now it's even more confusing. in the coment you say  `3 * (0) + 4 * (1-0)` which will give 4 as result but in the edited question you say `3*0+4(1-1)` which will give 0 as result. Is the 4 multiplying 1-0 or 1-1?

Comment: Fixed the typo in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
a2D = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a1D = np.array([1, 0])

# reshape the 1D array to 2D
b = a1D[:,None]
# concatenate b and 1-b column-wise, multiply by a2D and sum per row
out = (a2D * np.c_[b,1-b]).sum(1)
```

output: `array([1, 4])`

Comment: more efficient than what?

Comment: It seems they were using a loop (unspecified in the question) Regarding efficiency *per se*, difficult to comment on a 2x2 example, it depends on how the question generalizes. For a real 2x2 dataset a python list would be fine I guess…

Comment: Is your code much faster for say arrays with length 10,000? I'm comparing it to just using a typical for loop.

Comment: OK, so what I thought, a classical python loop (that is not efficient if the dataset it big). But sure if you really have only 2 columns, performing the one column multiplication + the other is perfectly fine

Comment: @Resu yes it should, try to never use for loops with numpy. Use vectorial operation whenever possible

Comment: @Resu Have a look at Kelly's link, if your real life example only has 2 columns, this is also a simple efficient way. Most numpy vector operation can be written similarly to what you would do with scalar